# Symfony Form Type constraint of string validates Integer value

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, fosrestbundle

I have a simple entity with three fields: an autogenerated ID, a string and an integer. I have set constraints for the latter two, and the constraint corresponding to the integer field works perfectly. If I send an integer which is not in the range, or should I send anything but an integer, then an error is returned.

However that does not happen with the string field. If I send an integer the form validates correctly. Why is that happening?

The code I am using for testing is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fieldOne": 9000, "fieldTwo": 5}' http://localhost:8000/foos
```

**FooController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\FooBar;
use AppBundle\Form\FooBarType;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class FooController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function getFooAction()
    {
        $view = new View();

        $data = array(
            'foo' => 'bar'
        );

        $view->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $view->setData($data);

        return $view;
    }

    public function postFooAction(Request $request)
    {
        $foobar = new FooBar();
        $form = $this->createForm(FooBarType::class, $foobar);

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form->submit($data);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            //$foobar = $form->getData();

            $response = new Response('All good');
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
            return $response;
        }
        return View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

**FooBarType.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class FooBarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fieldOne')
            ->add('fieldTwo')
        ;
    }
}
```

**FooBar Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * FooBar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo_bar")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FooBarRepository")
 */
class FooBar
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_one", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fieldOne;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 10,
     *      minMessage = "You must be at least {{ limit }}cm tall to enter",
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot be taller than {{ limit }}cm to enter"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_two", type="int")
     */
    private $fieldTwo;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fieldOne
     *
     * @param string $fieldOne
     *
     * @return FooBar
     */
    public function setFieldOne($fieldOne)
    {
        $this->fieldOne = $fieldOne;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fieldOne
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFieldOne()
    {
        return $this->fieldOne;
    }

    /**
     * Set fieldTwo
     *
     * @param int $fieldTwo
     *
     * @return FooBar
     */
    public function setFieldTwo($fieldTwo)
    {
        $this->fieldTwo = $fieldTwo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fieldOne
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFieldTwo()
    {
        return $this->fieldTwo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs during a typecast of the Form's submit method here:  [`Symfony\Component\Form\Form::submit()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L535)

```
if (false === $submittedData) {
    $submittedData = null;
} elseif (is_scalar($submittedData)) {
    $submittedData = (string) $submittedData;
}
```

The reason is to keep compatibility with a standard HTTP request always submitting values as string and to allow Symfony's [Form\Types](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types.html), to cast the values to the desired type.

*Keep in mind the parent Form is compound and each of the fields are children Form elements, which causes the typecasting to be performed.*

So for example:

```
$builder->add('a', Form\TextType::class, [
    'constraints' => [
       new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string'])
    ]
]);

$form = $builder->getForm();
$form->submit(['a' => 1]);
dump($form->getData);
dump($form->isValid());
```

Result:

```
 array:1 [▼
  "a" => "1"
 ]

 true
```

In this case `TextType` does not cast the value to anything, but the submit had already typecast the value to a string.

However it would fail validation when a `new Assert\Type(['type' => 'int'])` constraint was used, and the field type was not `Form\IntegerType`.

Whereas a Range constraint only tests for a numeric value that meets the min and max, which works on numeric strings as well.

Example: https://3v4l.org/ErQrC

```
$min = 1;
$max = 10;
$a = "5";
var_dump($a < $max && $a > $min); //true
```

Versus: https://3v4l.org/8D3N0

```
$min = 1;
$max = 10;
$a = "c";
var_dump($a < $max && $a > $min); //false
```

---

To resolve the issue you can create your own [constraint expression](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Expression.html), assuming you do not want a numeric value.

```
class FooBar
{

    //...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\Expression("this.isNotNumeric()")
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_one", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fieldOne;

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isNotNumeric()
    {
       return !is_numeric($this->fieldOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough clarification and the time you took to write it.